# Django ViewDoesNotExist error after installing photologue

Tags: django, django-views, photologue

I'm using Django 1.5.1. Everything was OK. But as soon as I installed django-photologue through pip I face this error when I visit admin url:

```
> **ViewDoesNotExist at /admin/**  
Could not import django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list. Parent module django.views.generic.list_detail does not exist.  
Request Method: GET  
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/  
Django Version: 1.5.1  
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist  
Exception Value:      
Could not import django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list. Parent module   django.views.generic.list_detail does not exist.  
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 104  
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python  
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Also when I run syncdb, photologue sync with database without any error and I can import it in shell.

Any idea about how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-photologue was most likely built for an older version of Django. Looks like the newer version of Django isn't friendly with generic views and prefers class based views instead.

Downloading a fresh copy of `Django 1.5.1` shows the following:
http://f.cl.ly/items/0k1J261S2J2f3k3C110I/Image%202013.04.20%203%3A44%3A39%20AM.png

Whereas `Django 1.4.2` shows:
http://f.cl.ly/items/152J2U050X0z1j1n0v0D/Image%202013.04.20%203%3A46%3A49%20AM.png

Simply put, the newer version of Django **removed** the `list_detail` file.

Answer (score 3):

to replace the file in the directory urls.py photologue :

```
"django.views.generic.date_based" and "django.views.generic.list_detail" on "django.views.generic" 

"object_list" on "list.ListView"
"object_detail" on "detail.DetailView"
"archive_year" on "dates.YearArchiveView"
"archive_month" on "dates.MonthArchiveView"
"archive_day" on "dates.DayArchiveView"
```

like this :)

or read :

Comment: This answer does not make sense to me. I have no idea what "and" and on mean in the above context. I think this documentation is likely to be more help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/